# How to let a div or span tag to receive a keydown event in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

For example,

```
<div onkeydown='alert(3)' style="background:yellow;height:300px;width:300px;">
Click at me first. and press a key to see the event
</div>
```

Here is a [jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/90mL8wfn/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify the tabindex on it.

For example,

```
<div onkeydown='alert(3)' tabindex="0" style="background:yellow;height:300px;width:300px;">
Click at me first. and press a key to see the event
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

For some reason the most simplest JS is not working on jsFiddle. Look here: http://plnkr.co/edit/SdAjLZujLgyXcTH5m2Js?p=preview

```
<input id="yellow" onkeydown="keyD()" onkeyup="keyU()" style="background:yellow;height:300px;width:300px;" value="Click at me first. and press a key to see the event" />

function keyD() {
    document.getElementById("yellow").style.backgroundColor = "blue";
}

function keyU() {
    document.getElementById("yellow").style.backgroundColor = "green";
}
```